# What is the difference between trackHistory and trackFeedHistory?

Tags: history-tracking, chatter-feed-tracking, field-history

If we look at the XML for a specific Object and inspect a random field, there is both `trackHistory` and `trackFeedHistory`

```
<fields>
  <fullName>AccountId</fullName>
  <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
  <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
```

Which one is for field history tracking? Or both? What is the relation between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**trackFeedHistory**
Will track changes to the Object in the Chatter Feed for that object. This is called Feed Tracked Changes.

- These Feed Items are system generated and refered to as FTCs
- FTCs older than 45 days are cleaned up automatically by the system.
- Follow the FLS rules (you will only see changes to Fields you have access to)
- It is customizable in the Setup UI for which fields / objects you are tracking.
- You can only track 20 fields per object type (such as an Account or Order).

More Information: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_feed_tracking_overview.htm

**trackHistory**
You can select certain fields to track and display the field history in the History related list of an object. The field history data is retained for up to 18 months.

You can enable field history tracking for standard objects in the object’s management settings.

When you enable tracking for an object, customize your page layouts to include the object’s history related list.

More Information: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm